# The order of transformations in a PDF document

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I read the following paragraph in the PDF Reference, 6th edition (2006).

> Figure 4.6 shows the effect of the order in which transformations are applied. The figure  shows  two  sequences  of  transformations  applied  to  a  coordinate  system. After each successive transformation, an outline of the letter n is drawn.

[image: Order of transformations]

I don't understand how step 2 in the second line is gotten by changing the order of the transformations in the first line.

Comment: It looks like there may be some [shearing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) mixed in with the rotation but that may just be me.

Comment: @WaveX is right, at step 2 the two dashed lines are clearly not perpendicular, but scaling and rotation should transform perpendicular lines to perpendicular lines.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Are you saying that step 2 in the 2nd line is not a rotation, even though the standard says "Rotation"?

Comment: If I had to guess I would say there is a hidden "Step 1.5" with a vertical / horizontal shearing followed by the rotation. That would help clear up why the dashed lines aren't perpendicular after the rotation like @Calvin Khor mentioned.

Comment: @WaveX: This doesn't make sense, since the paragraph introducing this diagram states: "Figure 4.6 shows the effect of the order in which transformations are applied". So the two lines must have the same transformations only in a different order. Can shearing maybe be simulated with translations, rotations and scaling?

Comment: @EvanAad yes, try rotating by 45º, then stretching in the horizontal direction. The result is a rotated shear. 

However, there is definitely nothing that I call a 'rotation' that can cause the picture in Step 2. This should be obvious: draw the $\Bbb n$ on a piece of paper, and rotate it. You will never distort the $\Bbb n$ like that (and if you use lined paper, you also see that rotations cannot distort the axes)

Comment: Isn't this the point of the diagram? That scaling then rotating introduces distortion because of the way in which the transformations are calculated? So the rotation calculation assumes, so to speak, that any scaling will take place later. Hence, if you scale first, you get a (typically) unwanted result. That's why you should not scale first.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, it *is* the point of the diagram. My question was not posed in order to figure out the point of the diagram; this was made clear to me immediately upon reading the introductory paragraph without even having to look at the diagram. My question was intended to understand *why* the sequence of steps listed in the bottom row produces the output seen in the diagram. I think I understand now.

Comment: My point was that you have to read the explanation of the calculations used for transformations and see the diagram in that context. Just taking it in isolation, it won't make sense, I don't think. So it is misleading to take that and then criticise it on the grounds that it doesn't seem to be a rotation. Of course not. That's the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every physical page, the PDF engine sets up a coordinate system that makes it possible to refer to every point on the page. For all intents and purposes, this coordinate system is immutable and is the only coordinate system that the engine's core "understands".

PDF transformations are handled by an intermediate layer between the user and the engine's core; the core itself is oblivious to the concept of transformations. The intermediate layer intercepts all the coordinates generated by the user, and resolves them to their absolute representations in the core's coordinate system, before passing them on to the core.

The intermediate layer composes a sequence of transformations on a *last* come, *first* applied basis. Thus, if the following sequence of transformations is applied by the user: $T_1, \dots, T_n$, the effective transformation applied by the intermediate layer is $T_1\circ\cdots\circ T_n$.

In the diagram's example, the transformations executed in the second line are: scaling ($S$), rotation ($R$), and translation ($T$), in this order. Therefore, the effective transformations applied by the intermediate layer after each step are: $S$, $S\circ R$ and $S\circ R\circ T$, respectively. In particular, if, once the rotation is executed, a coordinate $v$ is mentioned by the user, it will be resolved by the intermediate layer to the point at absolute coordinates $S\big(R(v)\big)$.

Suppose the scaling transformation scales the $x$-axis by $2$, but leaves the $y$ axis unchanged, and suppose the rotation transformation rotates by $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise. Let's see how the unit vectors $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$ are transformed.

Firstly the unit vectors are rotated by $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise. Since rotation preserves angles, the resulting vectors $u'=Ru$ and $v'=Ru$ will be perpendicular to each other, and symmetric about the $y$-axis.

Next, scaling is performed. Since the scaling is not uniform, and the scaling factor along the $y$-axis is $1$, the effect will be a shearing parallel to the $x$-axis, and $u'$ and $v'$ will be "pulled" in opposite directions, which will cause the angle between them to increase. In particular, the resulting vectors $u''=S(u')$ and $v''=S(v')$ will no longer be perpendicular to each other.

It is important to understand that all transformations are interpreted relative to the original coordinate system understood by the engine's core. For instance, in our example the scaling $S$ is not interpreted relative to the coordinate system determined by the rotated unit vectors $u'$ and $v'$. If this were the case, then $S$ would map $u'$ to $2u'$ and map $v'$ to itself, so that the new unit vectors $u''$ and $v''$ would remain perpendicular to each other. Instead $S$ maps $u$ to $2u$ and $v$ to itself, causing the angle between $u''$ and $v''$ to increase, as described in the previous paragraph.

---

I have applied this theory to recreate the illustration from the PDF manual using XeLaTeX with TikZ/PGF. I don't know what font was used in the manual, so I used the best approximation I could find, but it's not quite the same.

[image: A glyph and a rectangle under transformations]

The transformation matrices used are:

- $T$: A translation by $(.5cm,.9cm)$.
- $R$: A rotation by $30^\circ$ counter-clockwise.
- $S$: A scaling by $3$ along the $x$-axis.

To recreate the first line, the following transformation matrices were applied: 1. $T$, 2. $TR$, 3. $TRS$.

To recreate the second line, the following transformation matrices were applied: 1. $S$, 2. $SR$, 3. $SRT$.

Here's the complete code.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{heroout}[
Extension = .ttf,
Path = /Users/evanaad/Fonts/
]
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix
      {
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.01) {n};
          &[.5cm]
          \tikzset{cm={1,0,0,1,(.5,.9)}}
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \tikzset{reset cm}

          \makeatletter
          \pgfsys@transformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{.5cm}{.9cm}
          \makeatother
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.01) {n};
          &[0.2cm]
          \tikzset{cm={.866,.5,-.5,.866,(.5,.9)}}
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \tikzset{reset cm}

          \makeatletter
          \pgfsys@transformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{.5cm}{.9cm}
          \pgfsys@transformcm{.866}{.5}{-.5}{.866}{0pt}{0pt}
          \makeatother
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.01) {n};
          &[0.4cm]
          \tikzset{cm={2.598,1.5,-.5,.866,(.5cm,.9cm)}}
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \tikzset{reset cm}

          \makeatletter
          \pgfsys@transformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{.5cm}{.9cm}
          \pgfsys@transformcm{.866}{.5}{-.5}{.866}{0pt}{0pt}
          \pgfsys@transformcm{3}{0}{0}{1}{0pt}{0pt}
          \makeatother
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.03) {n};
          \\[3cm]
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.01) {n};
          &
          \tikzset{cm={3,0,0,1,(0,0)}}
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \tikzset{reset cm}

          \makeatletter
          \pgfsys@transformcm{3}{0}{0}{1}{0pt}{0pt}
          \makeatother
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.01) {n};
          &
          \tikzset{cm={2.598,.5,-1.5,.866,(0,0)}}
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \tikzset{reset cm}

          \makeatletter
          \pgfsys@transformcm{3}{0}{0}{1}{0pt}{0pt}
          \pgfsys@transformcm{.866}{.5}{-.5}{.866}{0pt}{0pt}
          \makeatother
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.01) {n};
          &
          \tikzset{cm={2.598,.5,-1.5,.866,(-1pt,29pt)}}
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1);
          \tikzset{reset cm}

          \makeatletter
          \pgfsys@transformcm{3}{0}{0}{1}{0pt}{0pt}
          \pgfsys@transformcm{.866}{.5}{-.5}{.866}{0pt}{0pt}
          \pgfsys@transformcm{1}{0}{0}{1}{.5cm}{.9cm}
          \makeatother
          \draw[dashed] (-.99,-.99) grid (.99,.99);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0.03) {n};
          \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

It’s very easy to misinterpret Figure 4.6. It might appear as if each step shows the result of transforming the preceding image, but that’s not what’s being shown. Rather, each step shows the result of re-executing the same operations with a further transformation added to the cascade. Of course there’s no rotation that will produce the Step 2 image on the second line from the Step 1 image, but *re*-rendering the outline of the ‘n’ after concatenating a rotation to the current transformation does.

With that in mind, the keys to understanding the effects of the transformations are that, they are applied to the coordinate system, not the points, and that they effectively represent how to map from the *new* coordinate system to the *old*, i.e., the inverse of what one might normally think of as the matrix of a coordinate system transformation. When it’s the coordinate system being transformed, points are transformed according to the *inverse* of that transformation, which together with the preceding means that when transforming a point from user space to device space, it is multiplied by the matrices in reverse order. For example, if, in PDF terms, we scale the $x$-direction by 3 and then rotate counterclockwise by 30°, i.e., set the current transformation to `[3 0 0 1 0 0] ct [30 cos 30 sin -30 sin 30 cos 0 0] ct`, points are transformed by the matrix $$\left(\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt3}2&\frac12&0\\-\frac12&\frac{\sqrt3}2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac13&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt3}2&-\frac12&0\\\frac12&\frac{\sqrt3}2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3\sqrt3}2 & -\frac32 & 0 \\ \frac12 & \frac{\sqrt3}2 & 0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix},$$ which transforms the unit square into the following parallelogram:

[image]

(Just to make things more confusing, I’m using the common mathematical convention of points as column vectors so that transformations are effected by left-multiplication by a matrix—the transpose of the PDF convention.) This is pretty much what you have at step 2 in the second sequence illustrated in your question. In effect, by rotating the points first, the scaling transformation becomes a shear.

---

Here are a couple of other ways to think about what’s going on. The color of a pixel in the page is determined by sampling the graphics. The mapping from page pixel coordinates to those in the graphics is determined by the current transformation, which warps the grid that’s used to locate points in the graphics. After scaling $x$ by 3, for instance, that grid becomes three times as dense in the in the $x$-direction, i.e., it goes from this

[image]

to this

[image]

which has the effect of stretching the image horizontally on the page. If you then rotate the coordinate system 30° counterclockwise, you end up with this grid:

[image]

To determine the color of a pixel on the page, sample the corresponding point in the graphics, using the transformed grid.

Instead of “pulling” pixels from the graphics to the page, we can instead think of “pushing” the graphics out to the page. This involves warping the graphics grid so that it aligns with the grid on the page, i.e., undoing the transformations that were done to the graphics grid, while bringing the image along through the same transformation. If you imagine warping the last grid so that it is once again uniform and aligned with the page, you should be able to see that the square will be transformed into the paralellogram in the first illustration above. Mathematically, this involves applying the inverse of the transformation that was used to change to coordinate system. As with any compound “undo” operation, the individual changes must be undone in the reverse order in which they were applied, which is why the order of the component transformations is reversed when inverting them.

Comment: If I wish to check what a coordinate transforms to, should I place the coordinate to the right (as a column vector) or to the left (as a row vector) of the transformation matrices?

Comment: @EvanAad I’m using the usual mathematical convention of left-multiplying column vectors by the transformation matrix—the coordinate goes on the right as a column vector. The opposite convention is common in computer graphics, though. I don’t remember off the top of my head what PDF/PostScript uses (it’s been many years since I’ve looked at that stuff), but if it’s the row-vector convention, then you’ll need to transpose the above matrix before applying it to a point. Also, the matrices are often $3\times2$ or $2\times3$, eliding the row/column that’s always $[0,0,1]$.

Comment: If this is the convention you chose, shouldn't the scaling matrix be on the right of the rotation matrix? Because if the first step is to scale the coordinate system, the first action that's applied to any given coordinate is also scaling (by the inverse), no?

Comment: @EvanAad No, because I’m inverting the transformation, which reverses the order of matrix multiplication: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: But why would you do so? The given transformations are performed sequentially, so the sequence must be preserved for the mathematical model to be adequate, no?

Comment: @EvanAad As I explained, when a transformation is described as being applied to the *coordinate system*, points are transformed by its inverse. The transformation being applied to the coordinate system scales and then rotates, so to map points you first rotate the point in the opposite direction and then scale by the inverse scale factors.

Comment: Say we have a sequence of coordinate transformations $\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots$ that are applied in this order. I agree with you that the transformation that a coordinate undergoes as a consequence of applying $\tau_i$ to the coordinate system is $\tau_i^{-1}$. But the order of application remains unchanged: $\tau_1^{-1}, \tau_2^{-1}, \dots$. Just think about the physical reality of a computer carrying out instructions one by one.

Comment: @EvanAad Think about the physical reality of “undo” operations on that same computer. In what order must you undo changes that you’ve made to an object to restore it to its initial state?

Comment: An "undo" operation will perform the transformations from last to first, but this is not what we are dealing with here. It's like we're in the North Pole and I'm asking you "Which way is the sky?" and you're pointing down, and when I say "But the sky is up!", you counter "But in the *South Pole* the sky is where I pointed at". This is all well and good, but we're not in the South Pole.

Comment: @EvanAad No, that’s **exactly** what we’re dealing with here. Going from the graphics space to the page image involves undoing all of the transformations. See my latest update to the answer.

Comment: @EvanAad One final update: it looks like the real source of misunderstanding is that you, and some others who commented on your question, were misinterpreting the illustrations. Looks like cfr caught onto this a bit before I did.